# Powerview connection error

Tags: sharepoint-2010, powerpivot

When I try to create a powerview report from an excel spreadsheet in Sharepoint, I get the following error message.

Please help

```
An error occurred while loading the model for the item or data source 'http://win-lnj1eq8qsfv:16350/PowerPivotTestSite/PowerPivot Gallery/Sum of Sales Quota.xlsx'. Verify that the connection information is correct and that you have permissions to access the data source.


<detail>
  <ErrorCode xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">rsCannotRetrieveModel</ErrorCode>
  <HttpStatus xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">400</HttpStatus>
  <Message xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">An error occurred while loading the model for the item or data source 'http://win-lnj1eq8qsfv:16350/PowerPivotTestSite/PowerPivot Gallery/Sum of Sales Quota.xlsx'. Verify that the connection information is correct and that you have permissions to access the data source.</Message>
  <HelpLink xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=20476&amp;EvtSrc=Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ErrorStrings&amp;EvtID=rsCannotRetrieveModel&amp;ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server%20Reporting%20Services&amp;ProdVer=11.0.2100.60</HelpLink>
  <ProductName xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services</ProductName>
  <ProductVersion xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">11.0.2100.60</ProductVersion>
  <ProductLocaleId xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">127</ProductLocaleId>
  <OperatingSystem xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">OsIndependent</OperatingSystem>
  <CountryLocaleId xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">1033</CountryLocaleId>
  <MoreInformation xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">
    <Source>ReportingServicesLibrary</Source>
    <Message msrs:ErrorCode="rsCannotRetrieveModel" msrs:HelpLink="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=20476&amp;EvtSrc=Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ErrorStrings&amp;EvtID=rsCannotRetrieveModel&amp;ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server%20Reporting%20Services&amp;ProdVer=11.0.2100.60" xmlns:msrs="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">An error occurred while loading the model for the item or data source 'http://win-lnj1eq8qsfv:16350/PowerPivotTestSite/PowerPivot Gallery/Sum of Sales Quota.xlsx'. Verify that the connection information is correct and that you have permissions to access the data source.</Message>
    <MoreInformation>
      <Source>Microsoft.ReportingServices.ProcessingCore</Source>
      <Message msrs:ErrorCode="rsErrorOpeningConnection" msrs:HelpLink="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=20476&amp;EvtSrc=Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ErrorStrings&amp;EvtID=rsErrorOpeningConnection&amp;ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server%20Reporting%20Services&amp;ProdVer=1.0" xmlns:msrs="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">Cannot create a connection to data source 'TemporaryDataSource'.</Message>
      <MoreInformation>
        <Source>Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient</Source>
        <Message>A connection cannot be made. Ensure that the server is running.</Message>
        <MoreInformation>
          <Source>Microsoft.AnalysisServices.SharePoint.Integration</Source>
          <Message></Message>
          <MoreInformation>
            <Source>Microsoft.AnalysisServices.SharePoint.Integration</Source>
            <Message>The PowerPivot service application could not connect to the Analysis Services instance.</Message>
          </MoreInformation>
        </MoreInformation>
      </MoreInformation>
    </MoreInformation>
  </MoreInformation>
  <Warnings xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices" />
</detail>
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically if you read through the error you can see **that it cannot open a connection to** the data source **TemporaryDataSource**:

```
<Message msrs:ErrorCode="rsErrorOpeningConnection" ....
    Cannot create a connection to data source 'TemporaryDataSource'.
</Message>
```

Check that you can access the Datasource manually - the connection string builder dialog should have a 'Test Connection' button.